# Solve Heat Flow PDE

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

The temperature for a rod is given by the equation
$\theta (x,t)=\sum A_n \sin (\frac {n\pi x}{l})e^{-\frac{k^2n^2\pi^2}{l^2}t}$
With conditions
$\theta (0,t)=\theta (l,t)=0$
And
$\theta (x,0)=\sin(\frac {\pi x}{l})$

I tried to solve this using Laplace  transform but it results in 0 value for $A_n $ where am I going wrong.

Note
$$A_n=\frac {2}{l}{ \int_{0}^{l}\sin(\pi x/l)\sin(n\pi x/l)~\mathrm dx} $$

If you think that my calculations are right and there may be an error in the question then please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the initial function $\theta(x,0)$ is precisely the $n=1$ term of the Fourier expansion with $A_1=1$.

In fact, this observation determines the Fourier coefficients completely. 
Alternatively you may evaluate the integral explicitly:

$$\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L \sin(\pi k x/L)\sin(\pi m x/L) \mathrm{d}x = \delta_{km}\quad \text{for}\quad k,m\in \mathbb{N}$$ which can be most easily proven by expanding the sines in a sum of exponentials via Euler's formula:

$$\sin{\pi/L k x} = \frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{i\pi/L k x} - e^{-i\pi/L k x}\right) $$
hence
$$ A_n = \frac{2}{2^2i^2L}\int_0^L \left\{ e^{i\pi/L (k+m) x}-e^{i\pi/L (k-m) x}-e^{-i\pi/L (k-m) x} + e^{-i\pi/L (k+m) x} \right\} \mathrm{d}x$$ Each term is easily integrated. For $k\neq m$ none of the terms contribute to the integral, while for $k=m$ the two middle ones contribute $-2L$.

In the present case $k=1$ implying $ A_1 = 1$ and $A_n=0$ else.

Comment: I didn't understand how you would prove the identity to kronecker delta. Can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: Also Here the value for k is 1. Is this right? I have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: @Sahil I updates the answer.  Try to do the integral over the exponentials yourself! And yes, $k=1$ in your case.

Comment: @Sahil: If you think this answer made your insight clearer and cleared your doubt, then please upvote it and accept it by clicking on the $\checkmark$ beneath the score bar above.